# How to plot a time intervals histogram using pandas?

Tags: pandas

Given a dataframe of intervals ('start time' and 'end time'), what would be an efficiant way to generate a histogram that show for each time point T, how many intervals are 'active' in it?

Code to generate a sample dataframe (apologies, I am sure there is a better way to do this):

```
from random import randint

intervals = []

for i in range(50):
    start = randint(0,50)
    intervals.append({'start':start, 'end':start+randint(0,50)})

intervals_df = pd.DataFrame(intervals)
```

**An example:**

For the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame([{'start':2,'end':5},{'start':3,'end':8},{'start':9,'end':10},{'start':4,'end':5}])
```

The matching graph would be similar to:

[image]

My intuition is that the time intervals need to be broken somehow to discrete values so they could be binned, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `apply` to generate the values for each range, then `melt` to reshape the data into long form.

```
In [113]: expanded = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(np.arange(row['start'], row['end'] + 1)), axis=1)

In [114]: expanded
Out[114]: 
   0   1   2   3   4   5
0  2   3   4   5 NaN NaN
1  3   4   5   6   7   8
2  9  10 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3  4   5 NaN NaN NaN NaN

In [115]: expanded = pd.melt(expanded)['value'].dropna()

In [116]: expanded
Out[116]: 
0      2
1      3
2      9
3      4
4      3
5      4
6     10
7      5
8      4
9      5
12     5
13     6
17     7
21     8
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

From there you could use the built-in histogram plot, or some other kind of binning.

```
In [117]: expanded.hist()
```

[image: hist]
￼

Comment: Brilliant! Many thanks. 
Trying to figure out what could lead to the gap between 5-6, since they are both on the list...

Answer (score 1):

chrisb's answer is great, but the reason why you have a gap between 5 and 6 is because the default number of bins is 10 by default. This means that the bins are distant by 0.8 in your case, so the gap is actually between 5.2 and 6.

A way to counteract this is to manually set the number of bins equal to the length of your data:

```
nb_bins = int(max(expanded) - min(expanded))
expanded.hist(bins = nb_bins)
```

Result:
[image]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCuJE.png)

Comment: please use an embedded image rather than a link

Comment: It was my intention but it seems I don't have enough reputation to do so, it's my first comment! ;)

Comment: we have been through this and you have to wait until you get enough reputation, members may down vote you which makes you lose points, so you have to start with one correct answer and not comments